# How to make custom module menu tab selected in backend

Tags: magento-1.9, backend

```
<menu>
      <place module="place">
        <title>Model</title>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>

        <action>place/adminhtml_place</action>
      </place>
    </menu>
```

This is Custom module menu tab. I click on it, it doesn't get selected. I tried to add `active` CSS class to it using `liParmas` but it doesn't add the class. If anyone know any simple trick to make it selected, please share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your menu active via your custom controller. Suppose the action that took place be `indexAction`, then it should looks like

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_setActiveMenu('place');
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

As you can see `_setActiveMenu` will do this job for you.

Comment: Wow..that was quite simple. I couldn't find a single thread about this issue. Hope this will help many. Thanks again.

Comment: happy to help you